# deno relative path issue

Tags: typescript, deno

I wanted to some prefixes for my imports like you can see in the code below:

```
"paths": {
          "~/*": ["../../libs/*"],
          "@/*": ["./*"]
        }
```

however I always get an `relative import path "@/config.ts" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ts(10001)` when I try to import anything `import User from "@/config.ts"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can alias import specifiers by using an [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). From [the Deno manual](https://deno.land/manual@v1.18.2/linking_to_external_code/import_maps):

> You can use import maps with the `--import-map=<FILE>` CLI flag.
>
> Example:
>
> **import_map.json**
>
> ```json
> {
>    "imports": {
>       "fmt/": "https://deno.land/std@0.125.0/fmt/"
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> **color.ts**
>
> ```ts
> import { red } from "fmt/colors.ts";
>
> console.log(red("hello world"));
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> $ deno run --import-map=import_map.json color.ts
> ```

---

Update: Here's an demonstration of importing a local module using an import map specifier (as [requested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071630/deno-relative-path-issue/71073700?noredirect=1#comment134978699_71073700) by [Kamafeather](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088045/kamafeather)):

```txt
% ls -AF
import_map.json     main.ts         path/

% cat import_map.json
{
  "imports": {
    "local/": "./path/to/local/modules/"
  }
}

% cat main.ts
import { shout } from "local/example.ts";

shout("hello world");

% ls -AF path/to/local/modules
example.ts

% cat path/to/local/modules/example.ts
export function shout(text: string): void {
  console.log(text.toUpperCase());
}

% deno --version
deno 1.34.3 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 11.5.150.2
typescript 5.0.4

% deno run --import-map=import_map.json main.ts
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: I'm still unable to make that work, when defining a bare specifier for some relative folder, like asked in the question. The example given in the answer explains only the case with a remote dependency. Would be great to have some example also for local relative deps and a bare specifier alias.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071630/deno-relative-path-issue/71073700?noredirect=1#comment134978699_71073700) @Kamafeather Sure — I updated the answer with a demonstration of that in the form of console i/o.